# I want to Convert JSON to Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON as follow:

```
{
  "83" : {
    "firstColumn" : 78,
    "secondColumn" : 76,
    "thirdColumn" : 51
  },
  "390" : {
    "firstColumn" : 48,
    "secondColumn" : 25,
    "thirdColumn" : 45
  },
  "454" : {
    "firstColumn" : 96,
    "secondColumn" : 55,
    "thirdColumn" : 65
  },
  "524" : {
    "firstColumn" : 0,
    "secondColumn" : 23,
    "thirdColumn" : 18
  }
}
```

I want to convert it to an array like this:

[[78,76,51,],[48,25,45],...[0,23,18]]

Comment: What should happen to the keys like `83`, `390`, etc?

Comment: array of what ? whith how many dimmensions ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.values()` to convert it to an array without holes, and ordered according to the numeric key values, and then map the array, and get the `Object.values()` of each object.

```js
const obj = { "83" : { "firstColumn" : 78, "secondColumn" : 76, "thirdColumn" : 51 }, "390" : { "firstColumn" : 48, "secondColumn" : 25, "thirdColumn" : 45 }, "454" : { "firstColumn" : 96, "secondColumn" : 55, "thirdColumn" : 65 }, "524" : { "firstColumn" : 0, "secondColumn" : 23, "thirdColumn" : 18 } }

const array = Object.values(obj).map(Object.values)

console.log(array)
```

Comment: I want my array looks like:

[[78,76,51,],[48,25,45],...]

Comment: See updated answer. Next time include an expected end result.